# how to fix 'Supplier not found' error during XML import into ShopWare 5.4.6

Tags: mysql, xml, phpmyadmin, shopware

i want upload 26 arcticels via xml.

i got the error: Supplier not found for article 1.

For me, the suppliers are currently not important. Main thing the articles are in it.

Is there a simple dirty way? For example, add Supplier via phpmyadmin?

I use this preconfigured Virtualbox: https://github.com/sl5net/lubuntu-shopware-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomment using a generic word like "unkown" in the supplier column. This should work.

The supplier can be found in the s_article_supplier table.

Comment: yes. you mean s_article**s**_supplier (not s_article_supplier)